# If a function is integrable, is it bounded almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f\geq 0$ is a measurable function with $\int f d\mu<\infty$, is it necessarily true that there exists a $M>0$ such that $f\leq M$ almost everywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1]$.

Comment: @RaziehNoori What is that value of $M$ so that $f<M$ almost everywhere?

Comment: you are quite right, my mistke,